# How to recreate a UnicodeDecodeError for testing in python?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, error-handling, python-unicode

So I'm just making a little csv parser and while working on it, I received an error that looked something like

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0
```

I was using

```
with open(<file>) as f:
    df = pandas.read_csv(f)
```

in order to read the file.

My solution was to use `error='ignore'` as an option inside the open() function (which I know is not best practice) but then recently I wanted to come back to it and do proper error handling by using a try/except block to catch the error and print a message instead of just ignoring it.

However, I can't seem to recreate the error. I'm using the same csv file with the same function and not getting the decoding error anymore...This is obviously annoying because if it happened randomly once, it might happen again and I want to properly handle it.

The character that caused an issue last time looked like a hyphen but bigger. The csv is huge so I can't find it anymore. I thought maybe it's an endash but when I copy/paste an "endash" I find on the web into the csv, I still don't get the error.

This might be a dumb question but how do I write non-utf-8 characters into my csv in order to recreate this error?

Comment: How exactly does the `open()` call look like? Just the file path? The default for the `encoding=` parameter is platform-dependent, so it might be the case that the error occurred eg. when the script was run on Linux, but not on Windows (where the default is often some 8-bit codepage).

Comment: It looks just as I have written above. Just the file path. And I'm using the same computer.

Comment: The error is in not knowing the character encoding of the file. Code cannot handle that. Also, there is no such thing as a non-utf-8 character. UTF-8 is a character encoding for the Unicode character set—it can encode the entire set. You could encode a file with a different character encoding but then reading with UTF-8 wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: You may create a byte string, and then decode it as UTF-8. `\xC0` is a invalid byte on UTF-8. You may try also with a emoji codepoint, and remove the first byte, then two emoji, and remove the last byte of the first one. So you will have the 3 most common cases (invalid byte, invalid initial byte, invalid sequence). -- I use emoji because so you can test also the handling of code point above 65535, not really necessary on your case, but so you have a more generic test case.

Answer (score 1):

Create a byte string with byte 80 in position 0 and decode it with UTF-8 to reproduce the same error:

```
>>> s = b'\x80'
>>> s.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```